# Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)

Tags: networking, apt, package-management, gcc

I am trying to install "GCC" and "GFORTRAN" using the command `sudo apt-get install gcc` and `sudo apt-get install gfortran`.

I have seen a solution related to this problem "Go to Software & Updates and change the server to the main server next to Download from.", but I am accessing a server via `ssh` command and not installing on PC. How do I solve this issue?

I get the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc
[sudo] password for ksjadhav:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libegl1-mesa libfwup1 libllvm9 libwayland-egl1-mesa
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gcc-7 libasan4 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcilkrts5 libgcc-7-dev libitm1 liblsan0 libmpx2 libquadmath0 libtsan0 libubsan0 linux-libc-dev manpages-dev
Suggested packages:
  gcc-multilib make autoconf automake libtool flex bison gcc-doc gcc-7-multilib gcc-7-doc gcc-7-locales libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg
  libasan4-dbg liblsan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg libubsan0-dbg libcilkrts5-dbg libmpx2-dbg libquadmath0-dbg glibc-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gcc gcc-7 libasan4 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcilkrts5 libgcc-7-dev libitm1 liblsan0 libmpx2 libquadmath0 libtsan0 libubsan0 linux-libc-dev
  manpages-dev
0 upgraded, 16 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 18.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 75.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y

Ign:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libitm1 amd64 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
Ign:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libatomic1 amd64 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
Ign:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libasan4 amd64 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04
Ign:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 liblsan0 amd64 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
Ign:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libtsan0 amd64 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
Ign:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libubsan0 amd64 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04
Ign:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libcilkrts5 amd64 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04
Ign:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libmpx2 amd64 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
Ign:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libquadmath0 amd64 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
Ign:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libgcc-7-dev amd64 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04
Ign:11 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gcc-7 amd64 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04
Ign:12 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gcc amd64 4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3
Ign:13 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libc-dev-bin amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1.2
Ign:14 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 4.15.0-118.119
Ign:15 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libc6-dev amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1.2
Ign:16 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 manpages-dev all 4.15-1
Err:16 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 manpages-dev all 4.15-1
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libitm1 amd64 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (43.255.166.254), connection timed out
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libatomic1 amd64 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libasan4 amd64 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 liblsan0 amd64 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libtsan0 amd64 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libubsan0 amd64 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libcilkrts5 amd64 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libmpx2 amd64 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libquadmath0 amd64 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libgcc-7-dev amd64 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gcc-7 amd64 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gcc amd64 4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libc-dev-bin amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1.2
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 4.15.0-118.119
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libc6-dev amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1.2
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-8/libitm1_8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (43.255.166.254), connection timed out
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-8/libatomic1_8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-7/libasan4_7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-8/liblsan0_8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-8/libtsan0_8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-7/libubsan0_7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-7/libcilkrts5_7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-8/libmpx2_8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-8/libquadmath0_8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-7/libgcc-7-dev_7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-7/gcc-7_7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-defaults/gcc_7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc-dev-bin_2.27-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_4.15.0-118.119_amd64.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6-dev_2.27-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/manpages/manpages-dev_4.15-1_all.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: I tried adding the lines "net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1" in sysctl.conf and ran "sudo sysctl --load". Now I get the following when I run "sudo apt-get install" ...."E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/manpages/manpages-dev_4.15-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:"

Comment: But if I am able to access the server remotely from my laptop using the "ssh" command, how can it be a network issue?